# Where do I put the option to ignore special characters with Regexp.new?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Here is the code:

```
def autocomplete
    if(params[:terms]) 

    key = params[:terms]
    customers = Customer.where(:$or => [
        {:first_name => Regexp.new(/^#{key}/i)},
        {:last_name => Regexp.new(/^#{key}/i)},
        {:email => Regexp.new(/^#{key}/i)},
        #{:phone => Regexp.new(/^#{key}[d+]/i)},

        {:phone => Regexp.new(/^#{key.gsub(/\D+/,'')}/)},

        {:zip_code => key.to_i },   
        {:street1 => Regexp.new(/#{key}/i)},
        {:street2 => Regexp.new(/#{key}/i)}
    ]   
  )
```

The gsub method suggested by Tin Man gets me almost there - it strips any non-Digit characters from the search string only when searching in the :phone field in my DB.

The last problem is that the :phone field in the DB might actually have non-Digits in it (and I want to allow users to enter phone numbers however they want), so I need to temporarily ignore dashes when I'm searching (using find() in Mongo)

Not sure if I should do it at this level in the autocomplete function or if I should do it in the autocomplete.js module...

SUMMARY - I want to :phone.gsub(/\D+/,'') but gsub only works on strings, not a reference like this.

Comment: You want a regex pattern so you can match `808949` if you pass in `808-949` or vice versa? Can't get there either way. We need better samples of the data you're trying to match and the input values.

Comment: If you're not a programmer you probably shouldn't be trying to fix bugs. Have you considered hiring somebody?

Comment: The firm I've hired is writing the code.  I'm the poor non-programmer owner of said code and doing my best to learn and understand - get enough of a foundation to be able to call bullshit without ever aiming to become a developer on my own.

I knew enough to come ask people smarter than I am about a problem I didn't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Some things I see:

```
Regexp.new(/^#{key}[d+]/i)}
```

`[\d+]` is nonsense. Drop the surrounding `[]`.

For:

```
{:zip_code => key.to_i },
```

Don't convert the zipcode to an integer. Some zip codes are hyphenated, which will drop the trailing value. Also, unless you intend to perform math on the value, leave it as a string.

What is `$or`? Using a global is usually a sign of code-smell. There are few reasons to use one in Ruby, and I've never found a good use for one in my code, and it's something that can usually be refactored out easily using a constant.

---

> I think you actually answered my question by pointing out the key.to_i for ZIP - that's actually exactly what I WANT to do with Phone Number - strip out all the dashes, spaces, brackets, etc. I am going to give that a try.

No, no, no, no. `to_i` won't do what you want. `'0-1'.to_i => 0` and `'0.1'.to_i => 0`. Instead you want to strip out all non-numeric characters from the string using `gsub`, then you're done:

```
'0.1'.gsub(/\D+/, '')
=> "01"
'123-456-7890'.gsub(/\D+/, '')
=> "1234567890"
'(123) 456 7890'.gsub(/\D+/, '')
=> "1234567890"

'0.1'.gsub(/\D+/, '').to_i
=> 1
```

Note what happened above when `to_i` received the `"01"`, the leading zero was removed because it wasn't significant for the representation of an Fixnum. You can force it to display using a string format, but why? A phone number is NOT a numeric value, it's a string value, even though it is a bunch of numbers. We NEVER need to do addition on them, or any math, so it's senseless to convert it to an integer. Keep it as a string of digits.

Comment: The Tin Man is right, `[\d+]` matches a `\d` (digit) or a `+`, while `[d+]` matched a `d` or a `+`. These are the kinds of things you don't just look up, you need a solid foundation before attempting to fix this stuff.

Comment: I think you actually answered my question by pointing out the key.to_i for ZIP - that's actually exactly what I WANT to do with Phone Number - strip out all the dashes, spaces, brackets, etc.  I am going to give that a try.

Comment: You rock - I'll play with this.